# Does Gitlab 8 automatically backup the LFS-Objects folder?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-lfs

Large file storage (Git-LFS) was introduced with Gitlab 8. I upgraded and activated it - but does Gitlab automatically backup the `lfs_storage_path` when I invoke `/opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create`? Or do I need to do that manually? 
Thanks, couldn't find a definitive answer via search / documentation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GitLab 8.2, (the latest stable right now) the lfs files are included in the backup. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/8-2-stable/lib/backup/lfs.rb

Comment: for anyone looking, the line where lfs is included in the default list of backup artefacts is here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/8-2-stable/lib/backup/manager.rb#L157